# digit sum of product of 185185...185*405405...405

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Try to find the digit sum of product of 185185...185*405405...405, i.e. 185 repeated 100 times multiplied by 405 repeated 100 times.

I know the answer is 2700, but don't know how to proof.

I know the following:

185 * 405=74925, digit sum of the product is 27;

185185 * 405405=75074924925, digit sum of the product is 54;

185185185 * 405405405=75075074924924925, digit sum of the product is 81;

so I guess for 185 repeated 100 times multiplied by 405 repeated 100 times, the digit sum of the product should be 27*100=2700.

I also find that:

185 * 540=99900, digit sum of the product is 27;

18185 * 540540=100099899900, digit sum of the product is 54;

185185185 * 540540540=100100099899899900, digit sum of the product is 81.

For the number 185, I know the following:

185 = 37 * 5;

37 * 3 = 111; 37 * 27 = 999;

185 * 405 = (37 * 5) * (27 * 15) = 999 * 75;

185 * 540 = (37 * 5) * (27 * 20) = 999 * 100.

How to proof that the digit sum of the product for 185 repeated 100 times multiplied by 405 repeated 100 times is 27*100=2700?

Both 185 and 405 could be transformed and keep the digit sum of product the same as the following:

851 * 405 = 344655,

518 * 405 = 209790,

185 * 540 = 99900,

851 * 540 = 459540,

518 * 540 = 279720,

with digit sum of all the products as 27.

And why is the digit sum of 185 * 405 as same as that of 185 * 540? Why does the digit sum of the product invariant under the transforms? Is this invariance a general thing?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Can you see a pattern?
$$\eqalign{185 \cdot 405 &= 749|25\cr
185185 \cdot 405405 &= 750|749|249|25\cr
185185185 \cdot 405405405 &= 750|750|749|249|249|25\cr
185185185185 \cdot 405405405405 &= 750|750|750|749|249|249|249|25\cr
185185185185185 \cdot 405405405405405 &= 750|750|750|750|749|249|249|249|249|25\cr
185185185185185185 \cdot 405405405405405405 &= 750|750|750|750|750|749|249|249|249|249|249|25\cr}$$

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I can see the pattern. But how to proof the pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Given any finite sequence of $k$ digits $d_kd_{k-1}\cdots d_1$,
let

- $(d_kd_{k-1}\cdots d_1)_{10}$ be the number $\sum\limits_{\ell=1}^k d_\ell 10^{\ell-1}$
- $\overline{d_kd_{k-1}\cdots d_1}^n$ be the finite sequence of $nk$ digits by repeating the $k$ digit sequence $n$ times.

It is easy to see

$$(\overline{d_k\ldots d_1}^n)_{10} = (d_k\ldots d_1)_{10}\frac{10^{kn}-1}{10^k-1}$$
Notice $185\cdot 405 = 999\cdot 75$, we have

$$(\overline{185}^{100})_{10}
(\overline{405}^{100})_{10}
= 75 \cdot 999\cdot \left[\frac{10^{300}-1}{999}\right]^2
= (\overline{075}^{100})_{10}(10^{300}-1)
= (\overline{\color{red}{075}}^{99}\color{orange}{074}\overline{\color{green}{924}}^{99}\color{blue}{925})_{10}
$$
So the digit sum we seek is
$$\underbrace{99(\color{red}{7+5}) + (\color{orange}{7+4})}_{100\cdot 12 - 1} + \underbrace{99(\color{green}{9+2+4}) + (\color{blue}{9+2+5})}_{100\cdot 15 + 1} = 100\cdot(12+15) = 2700$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understand the cases for 185 * 405. A further question is why the digit sum of the product invariants under the transform from 405 to 540? Is this invariance a general thing? Thanks.

Comment: @armeria As long as $a b$ is an integer multiple $n = (n_3n_2n_1)_{10}$ of $999$, the product equals to $N(100^{300}-1)$ where $N = (\overline{n_3n_2n_1}^{100})_{10}$. the upper half of that product is $N-1$ while the lower half is $10^{300} - N$. If you have a pair of $m$ digits number which sum to $(\overline{9}^m)_{10}$, the digit at same position of the pair always sum to $9$ and the final digit sum is always $9m$.

Comment: Thanks! How about the following invariance by shuffling the digits? 851 * 405 = 344655, 518 * 405 = 209790,  185 * 540 = 99900,  851 * 540 = 459540, 518 * 540 = 279720, with digit sum of all the products as 27. Is such invariance a general thing? Thanks.

Comment: the 5 product you metion are all multiple of $999$, this need not be true in general, eg $518\cdot 450 = 2331000$ isn't a multiple of $999$ and doesn't have digit sum $27$.

Comment: I know 450 will break the invariance because 450 is a different permutation of 405, while 540 keeps the order of digits. 518 and 851 also keep the order of digits of 185, while 158, 581 and 815 will not keep the order. So why does the permutation with order lead to invariance of digit sum of the product? Thanks.